# Question regarding portion of solution manual's argument to Chapter 19 Problem 36c of Spivak's Calculus

Tags: integration, summation, proof-explanation, upper-lower-bounds

In Chapter 19 of Spivak's *Calculus*, Problem 36c)'s author-provided solution makes the following claim:

> Supposing that $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$, then, for any partition $\{t_0=a,t_1,\cdots,t_{n-1},t_n=b\}$ of $[a,b]$, there exists a smallest and largest sum of the form $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^kf(x_i)(t_i-t_{i-1})$ where $k \in [1,n]$.

I interpreted this as saying that, for a given $k$, I can find vectors $\vec{x}=\{x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_k\}$ and $\vec{z}=\{z_1,z_2,\cdots,z_k\}$ where $x_i,z_i \in [a,b]$ such that across all vectors $\vec{y}=\{y_1,y_2,\cdots,y_k\}$ where $y_i \in [a,b]$ we have:

$$\sum_{i=1}^k f(x_i)(t_i-t_{i-1}) \leq \sum_{i=1}^k f(y_i)(t_i-t_{i-1})\leq \sum_{i=1}^k f(z_i)(t_i-t_{i-1})$$

My book has not really committed that much time on series (those appear in the future chapters), so I am not certain how to proceed. It is clear that there is a lower bound and an upper bound to the collection of all possible sums $\sum_{i=1}^k f(y_i)(t_i-t_{i-1})$...however, I am not certain how to show that the lower and upper bound are actually **in the image of** the "sum function" $\sum_{i=1}^k f(y_i)(t_i-t_{i-1})$. In fact, this strikes me as intuitively false...but the book says otherwise.

Edit: I have assumed here that the members of $\vec x$ and $\vec z$ must all be distinct...but if this restriction is relaxed, then I suppose the claim is fine. I suspect, though, that we need to have distinct members.

Comment: 1) Is $f$ assumed continuous? 2) Is $x_i,y_i,z_i\in[t_{i-1},t_i]$ assumed? 3) What makes you "suspect, though we need to have distinct members"?

Comment: @AnneBauval $f$ is not assumed to be continuous (the context of this overarching problem is specifically to investigate non-continuous functions). There are no assumptions provided regarding $x_i,y_i,z_i$...however, there is reference to Riemann sums in the introduction to the problem (which could, possibly, hint that your 2) is implicitly being applied). Regarding 3), I guess I just assumed that the author expected distinct values, given that the members $t_0,t_1,...$ of the partition are distinct...I suppose if your 2) is correct, though, then the $x_i, y_i,z_i$'s are all clearly distinct.

Comment: Not necessarily: you can have for instance $x_1=t_1=x_2.$

Comment: If $f$ is not continuous, the Riemann sums tied to $(t_0,\dots,t_k)$ may have no smallest and largest value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you misread your book(s). $x_1,\dots,x_n$ are fixed. The minimum and maximum values of $\sum_{i=1}^kf(x_i)(t_i-t_{i-1})$ are with respect to $k\in[1,n].$

Comment: I'll see if I can make sense of the proof using your interpretation. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: I am quite confident (I had a look at the solution manual).